# Angular - issue with integrating native Web Speech API

Tags: angular, angular-services, voice-recognition, webspeech-api

I am trying to integrate native [Web Speech API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Speech_API/Using_the_Web_Speech_API) without any 3rd party ngx library.

I could successfully integrate the API within my service. Voice recognition is also working and can generate text from recognized voice. But only issue I am facing in terminal there is an error -

> TypeError: speechRecognition is not a constructor

Here is my interface to access `window` -

```js
    export interface IWindow extends Window {
      webkitSpeechRecognition: any;
      webkitSpeechGrammarList: any;
      webkitSpeechRecognitionEvent: any;
      SpeechRecognition: any;
      SpeechGrammarList: any;
      SpeechRecognitionEvent: any;
    }
```

Here is my service function which is triggered in service constructor -

```js
        initializeNativeVoiceRecognition(){
            let speechRecognition = window.SpeechRecognition || window.webkitSpeechRecognition;

            this.recognition = new speechRecognition();
            this.recognition.lang = 'en-US';
            this.recognition.interimResults = false;
            this.recognition.maxAlternatives = 1;
        }
```

**I get terminal error from following line -**

`this.recognition = new speechRecognition();`

Just for reference, here are web speech API callbacks which are working fine -

```js
        initializeVoiceRecognitionCallback(){
            this.recognition.onresult = (event) => {
                var last = event.results.length - 1;
                var queryText = event.results[last][0].transcript;

                this.voiceText$.next(queryText);
            }

            this.recognition.onspeechend = () => {
                this.voiceActiveSectionStatus$.next(true);
            }

            this.recognition.onnomatch = (event) => {
                this.voiceActiveSectionStatus$.next(true);
                this.voiceText$.next('Voice does not match');
            }

            this.recognition.onerror = (event) => {
                this.voiceActiveSectionStatus$.next(true);
                this.voiceText$.next('Error when recognizing voice');
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure you keep the correct capitalization: it's `SpeechRecognition()` with uppercased `S`.

This should be the correct statement:

```
let recognition = new window.SpeechRecognition();
```

Comment: can you tell which browser you are using?

Comment: I am using Chrome. Your updated answer is not working as well. Also, tried with `new window.webkitSpeechRecognition()` according to another git issue. But still not working.